# How I can distinguish whitch /dev device is the phon1 in my router running openwrt?

Tags: linux, devices, openwrt

In my router (Fritzbox 7360) I havce installed openwrt, and I want to access at low level the port used for analogue telephony, so I can output some audio via it using a custom script or software.

In order to achieve this, I listed all the /dev devices:

```
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            60 Jan  1  1970 bus
crw-------    1 root     root        5,   1 Jan  1  1970 console
crw-------    1 root     root       10,  62 Jan  1  1970 cpu_dma_latency
crw-------    1 root     root      109,   0 Aug  5 19:36 dsl_cpe_api0
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        1,   7 Jan  1  1970 full
crw-------    1 root     root      254,   0 Jan  1  1970 gpiochip0
crw-------    1 root     root       10,  63 Jan  1  1970 gptu
crw-------    1 root     root       10, 183 Jan  1  1970 hwrng
crw-------    1 root     root        1,  11 Jan  1  1970 kmsg
srw-rw-rw-    1 root     root             0 Aug  5 19:36 log
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            60 Aug  5 19:36 mei_cpe
crw-------    1 root     root       90,   0 Jan  1  1970 mtd0
crw-------    1 root     root       90,   1 Jan  1  1970 mtd0ro
crw-------    1 root     root       90,   2 Jan  1  1970 mtd1
crw-------    1 root     root       90,   3 Jan  1  1970 mtd1ro
crw-------    1 root     root       90,   4 Jan  1  1970 mtd2
crw-------    1 root     root       90,   5 Jan  1  1970 mtd2ro
crw-------    1 root     root       90,   6 Jan  1  1970 mtd3
crw-------    1 root     root       90,   7 Jan  1  1970 mtd3ro
crw-------    1 root     root       90,   8 Jan  1  1970 mtd4
crw-------    1 root     root       90,   9 Jan  1  1970 mtd4ro
crw-------    1 root     root       90,  10 Jan  1  1970 mtd5
crw-------    1 root     root       90,  11 Jan  1  1970 mtd5ro
crw-------    1 root     root       90,  12 Jan  1  1970 mtd6
crw-------    1 root     root       90,  13 Jan  1  1970 mtd6ro
brw-------    1 root     root       31,   0 Jan  1  1970 mtdblock0
brw-------    1 root     root       31,   1 Jan  1  1970 mtdblock1
brw-------    1 root     root       31,   2 Jan  1  1970 mtdblock2
brw-------    1 root     root       31,   3 Jan  1  1970 mtdblock3
brw-------    1 root     root       31,   4 Jan  1  1970 mtdblock4
brw-------    1 root     root       31,   5 Jan  1  1970 mtdblock5
brw-------    1 root     root       31,   6 Jan  1  1970 mtdblock6
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        1,   3 Jan  1  1970 null
crw-------    1 root     root        1,   4 Jan  1  1970 port
crw-------    1 root     root      108,   0 Aug  5 19:36 ppp
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        5,   2 Aug  7 16:55 ptmx
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 pts
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        1,   8 Jan  1  1970 random
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 Jan  1  1970 shm -> /tmp/shm
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        5,   0 Jan  1  1970 tty
crw-rw----    1 root     dialout   251,   0 Jan  1  1970 ttyLTQ0
crw-------    1 root     root       10,  61 Jan  1  1970 ubi_ctrl
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        1,   9 Jan  1  1970 urandom
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      122,  10 Aug  7 14:17 vmmc10
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      122,  11 Aug  7 14:17 vmmc11
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      122,  12 Aug  7 14:17 vmmc12
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      122,  13 Aug  7 14:17 vmmc13
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      122,  14 Aug  7 14:17 vmmc14
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      122,  15 Aug  7 14:17 vmmc15
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      122,  16 Aug  7 14:17 vmmc16
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      122,  17 Aug  7 14:17 vmmc17
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      122,  18 Aug  7 14:17 vmmc18
crw-------    1 root     root       10, 130 Jan  1  1970 watchdog
crw-------    1 root     root      253,   0 Jan  1  1970 watchdog0
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        1,   5 Jan  1  1970 zero
```

But I do not know which one is the FON1 port in my router. Do you know a way how I can detect it?

Comment: If this is analog device/port I have my doubts you will see it as port in the list

Comment: Well given there is a device called ttyLTQ0 with a group of dialout, I would say that is a likely candidate, but who knows?

Comment: So if I see something I'll see it via sceen right. Any Idea how I can pass some random bytes to this device assuming it is a serial one?